# I am getting Null value error as java.lang.AssertionError: Lists differ at element [0]: != Selenium expected [] but found [Selenium]

Tags: java, html, selenium, automation

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"company_info\"]/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tblcompany\"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
List<WebElement> rows1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div//div//input"));
List<String> all_elements_text1=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<rows1.size(); i++){
    //loading text of each element in to array all_elements_text
   all_elements_text1.add(rows1.get(i).getText());
   System.out.println(rows1.get(i).getText());
}
```

I am getting all the Null values in the console window when i executed the above code

Comment: `.getText()` is not the same as `getAttribute("Value")`

Comment: Thanks....it's working for me!!!!!!